# Reading a directory on a client's computer using Java from a web based service (HTML)

Tags: java, html, web-services, jsp, external

I want to read a directory from a client's computer and get the contents of the files that are stored in that directory.
I already know how to read the files as well as get all the files, but when I try an external test (not localhost) I get a FileNotFound Exception, but when I try an internal test everything works perfectly.

Comment: You need to talk to a service on the clients computer which can provide what you need.  If the server cannot "see" the client, you must run helper code in a web browser which can do this.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen could I try pinging the client's computer to see if there is a connection or something similar to that (new to this type of work)?

Comment: Unless the clients computer is on the same physical network as the server, the server most likely cannot contact the client computer.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen thanks, I'm going to see what I can do